# How to restart setup wizard at first time startup?

Tags: boot, software-installation

I started up my raspberry pi, and accidentally pressed escape during new password creation.

The startup wizard exited, and now I cant get back to the startup wizard.

How do I restart the startup wizard?

Comment: sudo raspi-config

Comment: Use `sudo piwiz` in a terminal window

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Once you get to the end of the wizard, it will not reappear when your Pi is booted.

If you do want to use it again for some reason, just run it manually by typing (in the Desktop Run dialog)

```
sudo piwiz
```

Comment: How would you trigger it to show up again at next boot, as a one-off (i.e. mimicking first-boot behavior)?

Comment: Answering self: creating a file in `/etc/xdg/autostart`, the image comes with `piwiz.desktop` in that directory.